# Save as .csv not correct?

Tags: csv

My list with numbers in OpenOffice calc look so: http://prntscr.com/3hlqaa
and on save as .csv my parameters are: http://prntscr.com/3hlrms, as field delimetter "," but if i open this file with notepad i see it so:

```
546
5454
5456
5446
58654
8796
13211
```

but i need it to have so:

*546,5454,5456,5446,58654,8796,13211*

Can someone help me what i do wrong here?

Comment: csv generation will be 1 line per sheet row. If you want all the values in one line, you need to have the values all on the first row of the OpenOffice calc sheet. Excel works the same. That's just how it is. The logic is one row per record, one column per field.

Comment: Exist any way to convert it because my list is very, very large?

Comment: There should be a way to copy the data and paste it transposed. Excel does it, and I think I saw it in OpenOffice or LibreOffice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The export is correct, as @Frazz says there is "one line in csv for every row in excel file", if you want all the numbers in one line, there are several ways, i will use this PHP script:

```
<?
$file = file_get_contents("your_export_file.csv"); //Name of your file
$replaced_data = str_replace("\n",",",$file);
file_put_contents("new_export_file.csv",$replaced_data); //Desired name
?>
```

If you don't have PHP installed perhaps an advanced editor (*Notepad++, Sublime, Eclipse, Netbeans,..*) could do the job, just replace `\n` for `,`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the end-of-lines are not transformed to the delimiters.
If you put all the numbers in one line, it should work. At least it does in Excel (which seens to work similar).

You can use the Transpose function to get (a copy) in one line.
[https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_TRANSPOSE_function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_TRANSPOSE_function)